# Kinect + ROS + VMware Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, kinect, vmware, ros, vmware-workstation

I am using openni_kinect on a VM running ubuntu 11.10 . The host laptop runs windows 8 . 
When I run rviz I do not see any depth or RGB image , although the kinect is plugged in, roscore is running , and openni_kinect node has been launched

What is the issue ?

Comment: This question-answer may solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819171/kinect-primesense-xtion-ros-ubuntu-through-virtual-machine-vmware

Answer (score 2):

This question-answer is similar to your problem. So if @cassinaj 's answer doesn't give you any video, look here: [Kinect / Primesense (Xtion) ROS Ubuntu through Virtual Machine (VMware)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819171/kinect-primesense-xtion-ros-ubuntu-through-virtual-machine-vmware)

Answer (score 0):

If everything is running as you say, do the following if you haven't:

- Add an "Image" Display type. Use the *Add* Button at the bottom of
  the *Display Panel*
- Then go to *Image* in the *Display Panel* and select an *Image Topic*.

Alternatively, you can use the rqt_image_view plugin to display or check for image topics. Simply run `rosrun rqt_image_view rqt_image_view` then select a topic. Refresh the topic list if needed.

Cheers