# Kinect + ROS indigo + vm (Parallels) Mac OS -> Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: macos, ubuntu, kinect, ros, parallels

I try to run a Kinect, using ROS indigo and Ubuntu. Ubuntu is running in a virtual machine (Parallels) with Mac OS as an host.

I tried to test the Kinect via `rosrun openni_tracker openni_tracker`
with the error: 
`InitFromXml failed: Can't create any node of the requested type!`

Therefore I assume that the system can't access the Kinect. However, using `lsusb` returns: 
`Bus 004 Device 008: ID 045e:02b0 Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Motor` whenever i connect the Kinect

The following does not solve the problem:
http://answers.ros.org/question/9737/openni_tracker-initfromxml-failed-cant-create-any-node-of-the-requested-type/ (simply has no effect at all)

[Kinect / Primesense (Xtion) ROS Ubuntu through Virtual Machine (VMware)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819171/kinect-primesense-xtion-ros-ubuntu-through-virtual-machine-vmware) (different vm and host, also it seems to be a different problem)

If anyone could help me make open_tracker see the device, that would be very helpful.

Comment: VMs are incredibly bad at real-time USB connections, especially when they operated near some of the limits of USB. The Kinect (v1 I'm assuming) doesn't doesn't operate near the bandwidth limit, but has trouble when the timing is off. I've never heard of any case where the Kinect work reliably inside a VM (or even worked at all).